# Loop excel files, add one more column and save them in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a folder `D:/test/src` in which have lots of excel files, I want to add one more column `date` which is `2019-08-01` in each one and save them into another folder `D:/test/dst`.

Here is what I have done. It works, but a little bit slow. So if you have quicker or others ideas, welcome to share. Thanks at advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

src = "D:/test/src/*.xls*"
dst = "D:/test/dst/"

dfs = []
for file in glob.glob(src):
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df['date'] = "2019-08-01"
    df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(file)),
                index=False)
    dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: use multithreading

Comment: Thanks, could you show this in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

```
import glob
import threading
import pandas as pd

src = "D:/test/src/*.xls*"
dst = "D:/test/dst/"

def update(excel_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df['date'] = "2019-08-01"
    df["date"] = df["date"].astype(str)
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(excel_file)), index=False)

for file in glob.glob(src):
    threading.Thread(target=update, args=(file,)).start()
```